# Why my object Mock is not returning the value that i set with return_value?

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, mocking

In a file called jar.py i have a class called Jar, inside of this class i have a method called size(), that returns me how many items are inside of the Jar. This is use in other methods inside of the same class. Example, i have a method called "deposit()" the put items in the jar, but checks before how many items I already have.

I want to test the method using unittest. For testing deposit() I wanted to Mock the function size, to return a specific value (10).

```py
from jar import Jar
from unittest.mock import patch
import unittest

class JarTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch.object(Jar, 'size')
    def test_deposit(self, mock_size):
        jar_2 = Jar()
        mock_size.return_value = 10
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, jar_2.deposit, 20)
        self.assertEqual(jar_2.size, 10)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'
```

To check the response of the size function, I also tested it:

```py
class JarTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch.object(Jar, 'size')
    def test_size (self, mock_size):
        jar_2 = Jar()
        mock_size.return_value = 10
        self.assertEqual(jar_2.size, 10)
```

And then I got the following error:

```
AssertionError: <MagicMock name='size' id='140485140250832'> != 10
```

If have understood right, size is returning the Mock Object and not the value 10 like i want. Can anyone explain me why?

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually calling the `mock_size` in either of those tests, which unless you've defined `Jar.size` as a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), you should be doing.

Also testing with [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) should be done in a context manager.

The following works.

```py
class Jar:
    def size(self):
       pass  # does not matter since we're mocking it


import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestJar(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch.object(Jar, "size")
    def test_Jar_size(self, mock_size):
        mock_size.return_value = 10

        jar = Jar(20)

        self.assertEqual(jar.size(), 10)  # calling the method


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

many thanks for the answer. It helpt a lot. A problem that I faced, was that i used a decorator on the function "size()". after doing some research i found a way to get it running:

```
@patch('jar.Jar.size', property(MagicMock(return_value=10)))
```

Again, many thanks for your help!